# lxml xpath filter with OR condition not working

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

The langs object is a lxml object produced by parsing  this file:  http://www.loc.gov/standards/codelists/languages.xml

This xpath works:

```
langs.node.xpath("//lang:language[lang:name='English']", namespaces={'lang':'info:lc/xmlns/codelist-v1'})[0].findtext('lang:name', namespaces={'lang': 'info:lc/xmlns/codelist-v1'})
```

When I add an additional condition of **| lang:code = 'English'** like so:

```
langs.node.xpath("//lang:language[lang:name='English' | lang:code='English']", namespaces={'lang':'info:lc/xmlns/codelist-v1'})[0].findtext('lang:name', namespaces={'lang': 'info:lc/xmlns/codelist-v1'})
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1509, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml /lxml.etree.c:50717)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 318, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:145969)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 238, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:144977)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 223, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error  (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:144785)
XPathEvalError: Invalid type
```

Answer (score 7):

The correct syntax is `or`, not `|`:

```
nsmap={'lang': 'info:lc/xmlns/codelist-v1'}
langs.node.xpath("//lang:language[lang:name='English' or lang:code='English']",
  namespaces=nsmap)[0].findtext('lang:name', namespaces=nsmap)
```

Answer (score 3):

10 more minutes of googling and I had the answer:

I had the change **|** to **or**

```
langs.node.xpath("//lang:language[lang:name='English' or lang:code='English']", namespaces={'lang':'info:lc/xmlns/codelist-v1'})[0].findtext('lang:name', namespaces={'lang': 'info:lc/xmlns/codelist-v1'})
```

Comment: Very much the right answer. That said, I believe I hit "post comment" a good 30 seconds or so before you. :)

Comment: Yep: `|` is the *union* operator in XPath. Sometimes it can be used to the same effect as `or`, but only kinda by accident, unless you know what you're doing.